# How to detect if User isn't Pinching and Zooming In iOS Programming

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, uigesturerecognizer, gestures

Hello Devs (this is my first post in Stack-Overflow so please tell me anything in the comment that i did wrong :).

**This code detect if the the user is Pinching:**

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPinch = 
  [[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingerPinch:)] autorelease];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerPinch];
```

The Void Action:

```
- (void)twoFingerPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
  NSLog(@"Pinch scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
}
```

The issue is that I want to detect if the user hasn't pinched in under 20 seconds, so I can alert the user that @"Pinch to show more Images". I am using image Thumbnails and if the user pinches it will display more images. Thanks for your Help, and Have a great Holiday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start a timer with 20 seconds which will be invalidated only in `twoFingerPinch` method when the user pinches. Start this timer whenever you need to start checking for this. In the timer action method you can put the code to show this alert.

Declare timer in .h file,

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

In `viewDidLoad` or whichever method you want to start the timer for checking this,

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0f target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In `showAlert` method,

```
- (void)showAlert {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Pinch to show more Images" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

In `twoFingerPinch` method,

```
- (void)twoFingerPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
  NSLog(@"Pinch scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
  [self.timer invalidate];

  //if the timer needs to be restarted add,
  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0f target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: I understood much of the code exempt how to invalidated the twoFingerPinch, :)

Comment: You can use `invalidate` method on timer to cancel this timer when user does pinch gesture. Check the answer. Do you want to start the timer again when user pinches? In that case you can do invalidate and then do the initialization part again. Check the answer now. I have updated it.

Comment: Yes I would want the timer to Start Again.

Comment: Thank You and have a Great Holidays :)

Comment: This is actually pretty smart, if I ever need to i'll keep this in mind. +1